# svyglm and margins - variable not significant anymore as marginal effect

Tags: survey-weights, marginal-effect

I run a logistic regression with survey weights (only raking) with svyglm.
Thereafter, I calculated marginal effects with package margins (svyglm.margins).
However, one variable that is significant in the svyglm is not significant anymore when calculating marginal effects. Is this possible?

margins(svyglm-object, design = surveydesign, type = "response")

The variable is a categorical variable (language - german, french or italian). Also, the weighting is based on this variable.
The marginal effect of french is - 0.065 SE 0.04 z -1.6165 p 0.1060 lower -0.1438 upper 0.0143
In svyglm the coefficient is -0.47483 SE 0.27865 t value -1.704 Pr(>|t|) 0.088878

Thank you!!

Comment: Are there other variables in the model?

Comment: Hi Noah, thank you for your response. Yes, there are other variables in the model.

Comment: Marginal effects and regression slopes have different meanings, so why would you expect them to have the same p-value?

Comment: I only use binary variables, therefore I did not expect a large difference. But maybe then I don't understand the difference. I found a negative impact and wanted to see the effect size. However, the effect size is not significant. Marginal effects are nonlinear transformations of the estimated parameters in nonlinear models such as logit. Therefore, standard errors and p-values must be estimated using the delta method. This method is consistent but brings additional imprecision in the finite sample. Therefore, it is normal to get different decisions in tests.

Comment: However, I did not expect that I can conclude in one model, that there is a significant effect, and in the other model, there is not - especially since its all binary variables. I also thought it may be due to the calculation of robust standard errors. It could also be that the packages are not using the same robust standard errors. For svyglm I can find the method used. However, I cannot find it for margins.svyglm. However, since I can use a svyglm object in margins, I expect that the method should be the same.

Comment: They are two related but distinct quantities from the same model. This might not have anything to do with how the standard errors are calculated, but is just a fact of the two quantities being estimated. There is no reason the p-values should be exactly the same, even if there were no approximation in the standard error. Also, you keep referring to finding a significant effect from one but not the other. Significance is a property you impose on the estimate by selecting your threshold; if you selected a threshold of .15, they would both be significant; a threshold of .05, and neither is.

Comment: That said, the p-values for the two quantities are very close. You are making it seem like the two quantities yield vastly differing conclusions, but they do not. To me, the two estimates and p-values are perfectly compatible with each other. It may be that your doubt comes from black-and-white thinking of significance vs. non-significance. I see no disagreement between the two estimates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am now more confident in my results.